# SQL71501: Procedure contains an unresolved reference to an object

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures

We have a table called PrematureLoanSettlement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dim].[PrematureLoanSettlementRequest]
(
     [PrematureLoanSettlementRequestID]             INT             NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,[PrematureLoanSettlementRequestID_Primary]     BIGINT          NOT NULL
    ,[ContractID]                                   INT             NOT NULL    
    ,[RequestDateID]                                INT             NOT NULL

    ,[Created]                                      DATETIME        NOT NULL    DEFAULT GETDATE()
    ,[Modified]                                     DATETIME        NOT NULL    DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
GO
```

and in ETL procedure I want to update a column ContractID:

---

```
--  Update ContractID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF @DateID BETWEEN @MinDateID AND @MaxDateID
    BEGIN

        UPDATE stg.PrematureLoanSettlementRequest
        SET a.CountryId = b.ContractID
        SELECT ContractID, @SourceID, @CountryId

        FROM stg.PrematureLoanSettlementRequest a

                INNER JOIN dim.Contract b
                    ON a.ContractID = b.ContractID

        WHERE b.SourceID = @SourceID
            AND b.CountryId = @CountryId

        -- For existing
        UPDATE a
        SET a.ContractID = b.ContractID 
        FROM
            [stg].[PrematureLoanSettlementRequest] a

            JOIN [dim].[PrematureLoanSettlementRequest] b 
                ON a.[PrematureLoanSettlementRequestID_Primary] = b.[PrematureLoanSettlementRequestID_Primary]

        WHERE a.SourceID = @SourceID
            AND a.ContractID IS NULL        

        -- Others
        UPDATE [stg].[PrematureLoanSettlementRequest]
        SET ContractID = 19000101
        WHERE ContractID IS NULL

    END
```

which return an error for:

```
JOIN [dim].[PrematureLoanSettlementRequest] b 
                    ON a.[PrematureLoanSettlementRequestID_Primary] = **b.[PrematureLoanSettlementRequestID_Primary]**
```

> SQL71501: Procedure: [s01].[stgPrematureLoanSettlementRequest]
>   contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does
>   not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any
>   of the following objects:
>   [dim].[PrematureLoanSettlementRequest].[b]::[PrematureLoanSettlementRequestID_Primary],
>   [dim].[PrematureLoanSettlementRequest].[PrematureLoanSettlementRequestID_Primary]
>   or
>   [stg].[PrematureLoanSettlementRequest].[b]::[PrematureLoanSettlementRequestID_Primary].   Staging.Database    C:\Workspace\Projects\Staging.Database\SchemaObjects\Procedures\s01\stgPrematureLoanSettlementRequest.sql

Any help woul be appreciated.

Comment: If you explain what you want to do, there is probably a simpler way to express the query.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: I think you'll want to change the upper `set` `SET a.CountryId = b.ContractID` to match the lower one, like `SET a.ContractID = b.ContractID`

Answer (score 0):

You should ask *another* question providing sample data and what you want to do.  I suspect the code could be significantly simplified.

At least one problem in your current code is:

```
    UPDATE stg.PrematureLoanSettlementRequest
        SET a.CountryId = b.ContractID
```

Neither `a` nor `b` is defined.

Comment: also, I don't think he intends to set the countryID to a contractID

Comment: @Beth . . . No accounting for code that the OP has written.  Whatever the intention, `a` and `b` are undefined.